# Is it worth using memcached on node.js

Tags: node.js, memcached

Is there any particular reason to use memcached for fast access to cached data instead of just creating a global CACHE variable in the node program and using that?
Assume that the application will we running in one instance and not distributed across multiple machines.

The global variable option seems like it would be faster and more efficient but I wasn't sure if there was a good reason to not do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the size and number of items. If you're working with a few items of modest size and they don't need to be accessible to other node instances then using an object has a key/value store is fine. The one trick is that when you go to delete/remove items from the cache/object make sure you don't keep any other references to it, otherwise you will have a leak.